# Java Spring where place custom properties file

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to create a simple registration page. I am currently at the stage where I am trying to get data regarding the address from where the account activation links will be sent. For this purpose, I created the .properties file and placed it in the `"src/main/resources"` folder. Unfortunately, after starting the application and trying to download data I got an error.

**My class created for test:**

```
 public class GetConfig {
        public void getProperites() {
            try (InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/emailconfig.properties")) {

                Properties prop = new Properties();

                // load a properties file
                prop.load(input);

                // get the property value and print it out
                System.out.println(prop.getProperty("mail.adress"));
                System.out.println(prop.getProperty("mail.smtp.host"));
                System.out.println(prop.getProperty("mail.smtp.por"));
                System.out.println(prop.getProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.enable"));
                System.out.println(prop.getProperty("mail.smtp.auth"));

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
    at com.project.gym.mail.GetConfig.getProperites(GetConfig.java:19)
    at com.project.gym.GymApplication.main(GymApplication.java:21)
```

**emailconfig.properties file:**

```
mail.adress=myaddress@gmail.com
mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.smtp.port=465
mail.smtp.ssl.enable=true
mail.smtp.auth=true
```

From what I understood, Eclipse cannot find my file. **And here comes my question, where should I put my file to be visible, or how should I change the path to it to be correct?**

**Edit 1:**

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>gym</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>gym</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>14.1.5</vaadin.version>
    </properties>



    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.stefan</groupId>
            <artifactId>fullcalendar2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>



    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-addons</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

**Edit 2:**

After adding this to GetConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("emailconfig.properties")
```

I started getting these errors:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.project.gym.GymApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [emailconfig.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:184) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:319) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at com.project.gym.GymApplication.main(GymApplication.java:18) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [emailconfig.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:159) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:99) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:73) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:59) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource.<init>(ResourcePropertySource.java:67) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.DefaultPropertySourceFactory.createPropertySource(DefaultPropertySourceFactory.java:37) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processPropertySource(ConfigurationClassParser.java:455) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:274) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:194) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:298) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:202) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:170) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Is this a plain spring or a spring boot project?

Comment: Upload your pom.xml as well

Comment: something wrong with maven config  , can you show your pom?

Comment: If you're starting with Spring, you should be using Spring Boot (and it looks like you are). Read [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) and find out how to configure all of this mail setup magically (use `spring.mail.*`).

Comment: @khmarbaise I use spring boot.

Comment: @Kieveli I just added.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Hmm, Thank you for the information that something like this can be done. I tested it but I am geting new errors.

Answer (score 2):

Spring 3.1 introduces the @PropertySource annotation, as a convenient mechanism for adding property sources to the environment. This annotation is to be used in conjunction with Java-based configuration and the @Configuration annotation:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("emailconfig.properties")
public class PropertiesEmailConfig {
    //...
}
```

Comment: I tried It but I started to get a new type of error.

Comment: check [this](https://www.boraji.com/spring-4-propertysource-annotation-example) example, it may help